# Regarding Playing Music via Spinner in android

Tags: android, spinner

I have created a spinner view with some set of lists include. Now i wanted to play music while selecting those item list one by one....any idea....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi raghavan you can use this...

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    Uri data = Uri.parse("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath()+"/" + fileName);
    String type = "audio/mp3";
    intent.setDataAndType(data, type);
    startActivity(intent);
```

and in the filename variable pass the filename that you have selected in the list.
Hope this helps....

edit #1

```
final MediaPlayer mPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.reload);
mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //new Toast(getBaseContext());

        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;



    }
});
```

Insert this code inside your itemselect event...

Comment: @ Dinash thanx a lot.... I have 12 items on my spinner for each item one music will be played on selecting, how can i achieve this...

Comment: @Raghavan i ve some questions? 1. did you want to play a single audio file on each time a select is selected or play the selected audio file.. if yes just go through this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715554/need-help-in-mediaplayer-class/5715723#5715723) waiting for  your response..

Comment: @ Dinash s u r right...I want to play single audio file on each time a item is selected...And i am looking ur answer...

Comment: @Raghavan Did you went [through this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715554/need-help-in-mediaplayer-class/5715723#5715723)... It has the answer. check my answer in that and try....

Comment: @Dinash i have gone through but it is on a button click method... I want to play music OnItemSelectedListener   
        animal.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
         @Override
         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView adapter, View v, int i, long lng) {                //Code for playing music i have to write is it possible                          
         
         }
          
         @Override
         public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView arg0) {
         
         }
         });

Comment: you can use that for the listitem on select event also check my answer in that link...

Comment: @Dinash Ya i have got it.... but i am having 12mp3 files to be played on each item selection for each a every thing i should use this code...or some array method is there.....

Comment: I think you have to make a list 12 mediaplayer object and call the next one on its oncompletion method... I dont find any other way other than this... If you feel my answer is helpful then vote up me...